# Creating multiple if statements to display different Json data

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I have made a simple web app where it displays different news articles with AJAX and JSON data. I am adding the swipe functions now.

But I am having issues with the IF statements that I have made to check for certain data, then display the next set of data according to the current data. But my if statements don't seem to be displaying the right content even though the conditions are how they should be.

I have included the code and I have left a comment by the problem area.

I have also included two links under the code which contain a example of my JSON file and the swipe gesture library in case it is needed.

```js
var newsData;
var eventsData;
var nightData;
var dineData;
var outData;
var videoData;
var data;
var str = 'news';

function getposts(str) {
    var baseUrl = 'http://www.capetownetc.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug=';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET'
        , url: baseUrl + str
        , data: {
            get_param: 'value'
        }
        , dataType: 'json'
        , success: function postData(data) {
            if (str == 'news') {
                newsData = data;
                displayPosts(newsData);
            }
            if (str == 'events') {
                eventsData = data;
            }
            if (str == 'nightlife') {
                nightData = data;
            }
            if (str == 'dine') {
                dineData = data;
            }
            if (str == 'outdoors') {
                outData = data;
            }
            if (str == 'videos') {
                videoData = data;
            }
        }
    });
}

getposts('news');
getposts('events');
getposts('nightlife');
getposts('dine');
getposts('outdoors');
getposts('videos');

function displayPosts(str) {
    
    data = str;
    
    if (str == 'news') {
        data = newsData;
    }
    if (str == 'events') {
        data = eventsData;
    }
    if (str == 'nightlife') {
        data = nightData;
    }
    if (str == 'dine') {
        data = dineData;
    }
    if (str == 'outdoors') {
        data = outData;
    }
    if (str == 'videos') {
        data = videoData;
        getCatV();
    }
    
    var maxLength2 = 6;
    
    //IMAGE POST - 1
    var imgTitle1 = data.posts[0].title;
    imgTitle1 = imgTitle1.replace("Newsflash:", "");
    $('.ip1.text-heading').html(imgTitle1);
    var imgThumb1 = data.posts[0].thumbnail_images.full.url;
    $('.ip1.main-card-img1').css("background-image", "url(" + imgThumb1 + ")");
    
    //GET CATEGORY - 1
    function getCat1() {
        var category = data.posts[0].categories[1].title;
        $('.ip1.post-source').html(category + " / ");
        var pTime = data.posts[0].date;
        pTime = pTime.substr(10, maxLength2);
        $('.ip1.post-source').append(pTime);
    }
    
    //TEXT POST - 1
    var title1 = data.posts[1].title;
    title1 = title1.replace("Newsflash:", "");
    $('.p1.text-heading').html(title1);
    var ex1 = data.posts[1].excerpt;
    var maxLength = 100;
    ex1 = ex1.substr(0, maxLength);
    $('.p1.text-post-desc').html(ex1);
    var thumb1 = data.posts[1].thumbnail_images.full.url;
    $('.p1.card-img1').css("background-image", "url(" + thumb1 + ")");
    
    //GET CATEGORY - 2
    function getCat2() {
        var categoryP1 = data.posts[1].categories[1].title;
        $('.p1.post-source').html(categoryP1 + " / ");
        var pTimeP1 = data.posts[1].date;
        pTimeP1 = pTimeP1.substr(10, maxLength2);
        $('.p1.post-source').append(pTimeP1);
    }
    
    //TEXT POST - 2
    var title2 = data.posts[2].title;
    title2 = title2.replace("Newsflash:", "");
    $('.p2.text-heading').html(title2);
    var ex2 = data.posts[2].excerpt;
    ex2 = ex2.substr(0, maxLength);
    $('.p2.text-post-desc').html(ex2);
    var thumb2 = data.posts[2].thumbnail_images.full.url;
    $('.p2.card-img2').css("background-image", "url(" + thumb2 + ")");
    
    //GET CATEGORY - 3
    function getCat3() {
        var categoryP2 = data.posts[2].categories[1].title;
        $('.p2.post-source').html(categoryP2 + " / ");
        var pTimeP2 = data.posts[2].date;
        pTimeP2 = pTimeP2.substr(10, maxLength2);
        $('.p2.post-source').append(pTimeP2);
    }
    
    //TEXT POST - 3
    var title3 = data.posts[3].title;
    title3 = title3.replace("Newsflash:", "");
    $('.p3.text-heading').html(title3);
    var ex3 = data.posts[3].excerpt;
    ex3 = ex3.substr(0, maxLength);
    $('.p3.text-post-desc').html(ex3);
    var thumb3 = data.posts[3].thumbnail_images.full.url;
    $('.p3.card-img3').css("background-image", "url(" + thumb3 + ")");
    
    //GET CATEGORY - 4
    function getCat4() {
        var categoryP3 = data.posts[2].categories[1].title;
        $('.p3.post-source').html(categoryP3 + " / ");
        var pTimeP3 = data.posts[3].date;
        pTimeP3 = pTimeP3.substr(10, maxLength2);
        $('.p3.post-source').append(pTimeP3);
    }
    
    //GET CATEGORY - VIDEO
    function getCatV() {
        var category = data.posts[0].categories[0].title;
        $('.ip1.post-source').html(category + " / ");
        var pTime = data.posts[0].date;
        pTime = pTime.substr(10, maxLength2);
        $('.ip1.post-source').append(pTime);
    }
    
    //POST POPULATE ***
    
    $('#post1').click(function post1(str) {
        $('.post1').css('left', '0px');
        $('.post-header').css('left', '0px');
        $('.post-cont').css('left', '-9999px');
        $('.slider').css('left', '-9999px');
        //Image Post1
        var imgTitle1 = data.posts[0].title;
        imgTitle1 = imgTitle1.replace("Newsflash:", "");
        $('.post1.header').html(imgTitle1);
        var imgThumb1 = data.posts[0].thumbnail_images.full.url;
        $('#para-img').css("background-image", "url(" + imgThumb1 + ")");
        var text1 = data.posts[0].content;
        $('.post1.text').html(text1);
        var category = data.posts[0].categories[1].title;
        $('.lay2.post-source').html(category + " / ");
        var maxLength2 = 6;
        var pTime = data.posts[0].date;
        pTime = pTime.substr(10, maxLength2);
        $('.lay2.post-source').append(pTime);
        //GET TAGS
        //        function getTags(){
        //            for (var i = 0; i < data.posts.length; i++) {
        //            var newTag = "<li>" + "<input type='checkbox' value=' ' class='tag'>" + "<label for='tag'                 class='post inter-label" + "'>" + data.posts[0].tags[i].title + "</label>" + "</li>";
        //            $('.tag-list').append(newTag);
        //        }}
        //        getTags();
    });
    
    $('#post2').click(function post1(str) {
        $('.post1').css('left', '0px');
        $('.post-header').css('left', '0px');
        $('.post-cont').css('left', '-9999px');
        $('.slider').css('left', '-9999px');
        //Image Post1
        var imgTitle1 = data.posts[1].title;
        imgTitle1 = imgTitle1.replace("Newsflash:", "");
        $('.post1.header').html(imgTitle1);
        var imgThumb1 = data.posts[1].thumbnail_images.full.url;
        $('#para-img').css("background-image", "url(" + imgThumb1 + ")");
        var text1 = data.posts[1].content;
        $('.post1.text').html(text1);
        var category = data.posts[1].categories[1].title;
        $('.lay2.post-source').html(category + " / ");
        var maxLength2 = 6;
        var pTime = data.posts[1].date;
        pTime = pTime.substr(10, maxLength2);
        $('.lay2.post-source').append(pTime);
    });
    
    $('#post3').click(function post1(str) {
        $('.post1').css('left', '0px');
        $('.post-header').css('left', '0px');
        $('.post-cont').css('left', '-9999px');
        $('.slider').css('left', '-9999px');
        //Image Post1
        var imgTitle1 = data.posts[2].title;
        imgTitle1 = imgTitle1.replace("Newsflash:", "");
        $('.post1.header').html(imgTitle1);
        var imgThumb1 = data.posts[2].thumbnail_images.full.url;
        $('#para-img').css("background-image", "url(" + imgThumb1 + ")");
        var text1 = data.posts[2].content;
        $('.post1.text').html(text1);
        var category = data.posts[2].categories[1].title;
        $('.lay2.post-source').html(category + " / ");
        var maxLength2 = 6;
        var pTime = data.posts[2].date;
        pTime = pTime.substr(10, maxLength2);
        $('.lay2.post-source').append(pTime);
    });
    
    $('#post4').click(function post1(str) {
        $('.post1').css('left', '0px');
        $('.post-header').css('left', '0px');
        $('.post-cont').css('left', '-9999px');
        $('.slider').css('left', '-9999px');
        //Image Post1
        var imgTitle1 = data.posts[3].title;
        imgTitle1 = imgTitle1.replace("Newsflash:", "");
        $('.post1.header').html(imgTitle1);
        var imgThumb1 = data.posts[3].thumbnail_images.full.url;
        $('#para-img').css("background-image", "url(" + imgThumb1 + ")");
        var text1 = data.posts[3].content;
        $('.post1.text').html(text1);
        var category = data.posts[3].categories[1].title;
        $('.lay2.post-source').html(category + " / ");
        var maxLength2 = 6;
        var pTime = data.posts[3].date;
        pTime = pTime.substr(10, maxLength2);
        $('.lay2.post-source').append(pTime);
    });
    getCat1();
    getCat2();
    getCat3();
    getCat4();
    
$('#swipe').bind('swiperight', function(){

});
// **** PROBLEM AREA ****
$('#swipe').bind('swipeleft', function(){
if(data == newsData){
    displayPosts('events');
}
else if(data == eventsData){
    displayPosts('nightlife');
}
else if(data == nightData){
    displayPosts('dine');
}
console.log(data);
});
    
} //End of displayPosts
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider interest-slider">
                    <div data-index="news">
                        <p onclick="displayPosts('news')">Home</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p onclick="displayPosts('events')">Events</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p onclick="displayPosts('nightlife')">Nightlife</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p onclick="displayPosts('dine')">Dine</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p onclick="displayPosts('outdoors')">Outdoors</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p onclick="displayPosts('videos')">Video</p>
                    </div>
</div>
```

[Swipe function library - JGestures](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=69369777705539461509)

[Example of Json Data file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00204955091581473277)

Comment: You should use `switch` instead of `if` conditions;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "displayPosts"  function doesn't look right. You only call in from the "news" if statement for a start, but also you're passing in only one parameter, the data. You're ten checking this parameter for the mode. It looks like you should be passing in the type instead.

Having said this, I'd stop using the global variables completely and pass both the mode and the data in as two parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will take a look at that and let you know :)

Comment: In terms of your swipe, I would again check the type/mode rather than the data itself, you may find this works better for you.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner here. When you say type/mode what are you referring to? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "news" or "events", etc.

Comment: Hey thank you for your help, it actually works comparing the "news" and "events" like you suggested. I now just need to set the str value to 'news' because it is only added with the onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

You should use `switch / if...else` construct in such case when you are comparing a variable with multiple values because this way you can skip further check if matches found.

**Using switch:**

```
success: function postData(data){
    switch(str){
      case 'news':
        newsData = data;
        displayPosts(newsData);
        break;
      case 'events':
        eventsData = data;
        break;
      case 'nightlife':
        nightData = data;
        break;
      case 'dine':
        dineData = data;
        break;
      case 'outdoors':
        outData = data;
        break;
      case 'videos':
        videoData = data;
        break;
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**

```
switch(str){
  case 'news':
    data = newsData;
    break;
  case 'events':
    data = eventsData;
    break;
  case 'nightlife':
    data = nightData;
    break;
  case 'dine':
    data = dineData;
    break;
  case 'outdoors':
    data = outData;
    break;
  case 'videos':
    data = videoData;
    getCatV();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That does seem like a better option. But I see you are using it in the postData function/ Ajax success function. But I need it for the swipe function which is highlighted with a comment. Should I use the same switch method but just put it in the swipe function?

Comment: Yes for the `displayPosts` if condition you should use the `switch`;